# validate resource references inside Android Xml file

Tags: android, android-manifest

In AndroidManifest.xml file it show the this error.

Error : Validate resource refrence inside Android xml file

```
<activity android:name=".view.ListUsersActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.redvelvet.abhi.github.view.ListUsersActivity" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

I have tried some solutions mentioned on stackOverflow but didn't work out.

```
styles.xml

<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
</resources>
```

Comment: What's inside your `styles.xml`?

Comment: What are you planning to have with intent filter?

Comment: I had two activities, Initially I put both in different packages So I just tried a solution mention [here] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27664926/validates-resource-references-inside-android-xml-files)